# How to install git patches?

Tags: git

Hi I'm sorry if this is a really stupid question but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to install solr patches. I want to install this patch

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9185

All I'm using is the solr-6.1.0 release which I uncompressed to my Documents directory. I got solr working, added a core etc. and managed to move it to my Ubuntu server but I have no idea how to apply that patch either my local version or the server. Thanks

Comment: You can find some instructions here: https://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/

Comment: @VladimirVagaytsev So do I have to download an uncompiled version from the git repository and apply the patch to that and rebuild it? Is it impossible to patch just the standard Solr 6.1.0 downloaded from the official releases?

Comment: @Kiibo, unfortunately you can't directly patch solr binaries. You have to clone the solr repo, then apply the patch and rebuild the binaries. Looks like you want to use custom query parser, so you can build it as standalone jar, then register it in your `solrconfig.xml`and put the built jar to solr's `lib` folder

Comment: @VladimirVagaytsev okay so just to check my understanding and sorry if this is very basic im new to all this. I can apply the patch to the QueryParser.jj from the clone of the solr repo, then build that as a jar and import that jar to my functioning version of solr on my server?

Comment: @Kiibo, you can find some instructions here: https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-own It covers basic steps to implement own parser and plug it into solr.

Comment: @VladimirVagaytsev Thanks for all the help!